# How a new string object is created when a character is concatenated to it using'+' operator in Java?

Tags: java, string, object, time-complexity

When I was learning about strings, I encountered a code snippet of string concatenation in java with the deduced time complexity of O(N<sup>2</sup>)

```
String str="";
char ch='a';
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)//n is the input variable
{
  str=str+ch;
  ch++;
}
```

Upon further investigation I found that,
The 'for' loop runs 26 times and next alphabet is added to the string each time the loops iterate so, if new object is being created every time due to the immutable nature of stings,
It would have the time complexity of O(N) assuming that creation of string objects takes constant time,

So, can you explain me how new String objects in java are being created which leads to the time complexity of O(N<sup>2</sup>) for this code snippet?

I was learning about Strings and its concatenation and encountered a code snippet of string concatenation with the deduced time complexity of O(N<sup>2</sup>) but I was expecting it to be O(N) assuming that creation of strings takes constant time.

Comment: This doesn't run in `O(n)` or `O(n²)` since there's no variable input `n` here. This runs exactly 26 iterations i. e. a constant amount of iterations => this runs in constant time `O(1)`, assuming of course you count all the operations in the loop as contant operations, which you would normally in this case.

Comment: @Mushroomator A for-loop where n is the number of iterations runs in O(1) , are you kidding?

Comment: The question has been changed now, considerably. The loop was hardcoded to run 26 times i. e. `i < 26`.

Comment: So `n=26` which leads to O(n) = O(26). And since each process inside the loop is assumed to be constant there is no n2, but still linear.

Comment: The time it takes to create the new string itself is also O(N), because it contains N chars which need to be copied into the new string. This is what makes it O(N^2)

Comment: Where is `n` defined?

Comment: It all depends on whether `n` is a variable input (i. e. provided by the caller of the code) into the function or not. They way it was it was not, therefore `O(1)`. The way it is now `n` seems to be a variable input which means `O(n)` again if you consider creating a string a constant operation which you would typically do in languages like Java. Of course behind the scences due to the fact that strings are immutable a new string would need to be created and the value would need to be copied over. If you want to count that than you'd end up at `O(n²)`.

Comment: @Slevin *O(26) = O(1)*, by definition.

Answer (score 3):

> When I was learning about strings, I encountered a code snippet of string concatenation in java with the deduced time complexity of O(N2)

Yes.

> if new object is being created every time due to the immutable nature of stings, It would have the time complexity of O(N)

No.

> assuming that creation of string objects takes constant time,

That assumption is wrong.

---

When you write:

```
String a = readInput(); // 'abc' is read
String b = readInput(); // 'def' is read

String c = a + b;
```

What ends up happening is that `a + b` is compiled as a call to `String.concat`, and that works something like this:

```
public static String concat(String a, String b) {
  char[] x = new char[a.length() + b.length()];
  int pos = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    x[pos++] = a.charAt(i);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
    x[pos++] = b.charAt(i);
  }
  return String.wrap(x);
}
```

**That** is `O(z)` where z stands for the sum of the lengths of the two input strings. And you do that `n` times, where n stands for the amount of strings you are concatenating.

So, the total operation's time is `O(n*(n+z))` where 'n' is amount of strings and z is average length of each string.

When discussing big-O notation folks have the very very nasty tendency of not explaining what the `n` stands for. It's a common error that you should endeavour not to make. However, that does explain: **most** folks incorrectly simplify the correct statement: `Performance characteristic is O(n*(n+z)) where n is ... and z is ....` to `Performance characteristic is O(n^2)`. That's a fair simplification here, as 'sum of the lengths of the inputs' *itself* scales with `n`, as one of the two inputs for each concat operation is the string you're setting up.